# Broken Mercurial Repo

Tags: linux, version-control, mercurial

I did a revursive sed on my root directory, and when I tried to commit, or do anything with hg besides hg --help, I get a stack trace. I incorrectly assumed that the .hg directory was write protected when I did my sed.

The repo is local to my machine.

Is there any way for me to recover my changelog or commit comments? I found a file called `00changelog.i` in the `.hg` dir, but it's a binary file that doesn't execute.

The sed commands:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i.bak "s/sim-config.h/config.h/g" {} \;
find . -type f -exec sed -i.bak "s/av-config.h/config.h/g" {} \;
```

The stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/hg", line 27, in <module>
    mercurial.dispatch.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 16, in run
    sys.exit(dispatch(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 30, in dispatch
    return _runcatch(u, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 50, in _runcatch
    return _dispatch(ui, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 470, in _dispatch
    return runcommand(lui, repo, cmd, fullargs, ui, options, d)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 340, in runcommand
    ret = _runcommand(ui, options, cmd, d)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 521, in _runcommand
    return checkargs()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 475, in checkargs
return cmdfunc()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 469, in <lambda>
    d = lambda: util.checksignature(func)(ui, *args, **cmdoptions)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 401, in check
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/commands.py", line 712, in commit
    node = cmdutil.commit(ui, repo, commitfunc, pats, opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/cmdutil.py", line 1151, in commit
    return commitfunc(ui, repo, message, match(repo, pats, opts), opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/commands.py", line 710, in commitfunc
    editor=e, extra=extra)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/localrepo.py", line 787, in commit
    changes = self.status(match=match, clean=force)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/localrepo.py", line 1015, in status
    listclean, listunknown)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dirstate.py", line 614, in status
    dmap = self._map
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 156, in __get__
    result = self.func(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dirstate.py", line 58, in _map
    self._read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dirstate.py", line 228, in _read
    p = parsers.parse_dirstate(self._map, self._copymap, st)
```

Comment: Do you have an upstream repo that you cloned from? How many commits were in your local repo that are not in your upstream?

Comment: There was no upstream repo, so all of them. I was coding in the repo itself.

Comment: What `sed` command did you run? What is the stack trace you get?

Answer (score 1):

If you have no upstream source that you can replace the `.hg` clone with, it will probably depend on how badly mucked up the files are. However, as you noticed, Mercurial stores files internally in a binary format which will make it harder to repair by hand.

Presumably you did not run with `sed -i.bak` to do an in-place with a backup (which would make it easy to restore).

You can do something like:

```
find .hg -mmin -60 -print
```

to see which files were modified in the past (say) 60 minutes. Maybe not too much was modified and you can find some way to reverse the effects of the `sed` command on that file (but that would be impossible if you ran something like `/foo/d`).

For the future, it may be worth signing up for a free account on http://bitbucket.org/ which will give you free private repository hosting and a good backup location.

Comment: I actually did run the sed with -i.bak. I had completely forgotten about that. The thing is, I ran a few different seds and have .bak.bak.bak and so on. How would I go about restoring it?

Comment: Disregard that, I don't have the .baks

Comment: If you actually had a `.bak` file, you would need to go find them and replace (e.g.) `mv 00changelog.i.bak 00changelog.i`.